# What this declaration of the argument mean: "type (*name1) (const type& name2)"?

Tags: c++, pointers

In the code that I need to modify there is a declaration of a function that has several arguments. Every argument, as expected is declared in the following way: `arg_type arg_name`. However, on of the arguments is declared in the following way: `bool (*filter) (const row<aaa::bbb>& entity)` and I do not understand this declaration.

So, I think we have an argument that can have boolean values but what do `(*filter)` and `(const row<aaa::bbb>& entity)` mean?

**ADDED**

To make it more clear, here is more context:

`void func(int a, double b, bool (*filter) (const row<aaa::bbb>& entity))`.

**ADDED 2**

Does it work in this way?

```
bool myFilter( const row<aaa::bbb>& e) { /* ... */ }

bool applyFilter( bool (*filter)(const row<aaa::bbb>& entity, bool& x)){
   return filter(x&entity);
}

applyFilter(myFilter entity, x);
```

Comment: I don't think this is inherently a downvotable question, this kind of declaration is not easy to find on google. However, it would be good to mention what you have tried already.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
bool (*filter) (const row<aaa::bbb>& entity)
```

`filter` is a pointer to a function, that takes a `const row<aaa::bbb>&` as only parameter and returns a `bool`.

#### Example

```
bool myFilter( const row<aaa::bbb>& e) { /* ... */ }

bool applyFilter( bool (*filter)(const row<aaa::bbb>&)){
    return filter(somerow);
}
```

Comment: So, I have a declaration of a function on the place where a declaration of an argument should be?

Comment: @Roman: No. You have a variable `filter` which has the type `bool (*)(const row<aaa::bbb>)`, which is a function pointer type.

Comment: in my example there is also `entity` (and in your example it's not there). Why is that? And if `entity` is there, how is it used in the body of the function declaration and how the function (applyFilter) should be called? Should I pass argument o the `filter` too?

Comment: @Roman: It's not really important to the function pointer, which needs only a valid signature. It's completely optional. However, it is a hind to you what the parameter should be

Answer (score 2):

It declares a pointer variable named `filter`, which points to a function (instead of to an object like you are probably used to) with the signature `bool(const row<aaa::bbb>&)`,  meaning a functions which takes an `row<aaa::bbb>` by const ref and return a `bool`.

The syntax to declare a function pointer in C++ is generally `return-type (*variable-name)(argument-list)`, giving you a variable named `variable-name` of type `returntype (*)(argument-list)`, to  which is a bit strange, but you get used to it.

Comment: @Roman: Just like a normal function signature `entity` is the name of the parameter.

Comment: I do not understand how `entity` is used. This name is present in the argument part of the function declaration. How is it then used in the body of the declared function and how the declared function can be called to pass the entity? Is it needed to be passed?